# jQuery set element attribute without altering function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, rss

I'm trying to pull the link from an rss feed using the jQuery-rss script (https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) to insert it into an 'a' element href.

I know that this can be done by doing

```
$("#rss-link").attr(href, "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss"
```

but that would only embed the rss feed link rather than the link to the rss item.

Here is my script:

```
jQuery(function(link) {
     $("#rss-link").rss("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss", {
          entryTemplate: '{url}',
          limit: '1'
        })
      });
```

What is the correct way to do this?
I'm not very experienced with jQuery so anything helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `href` name of your class?

Comment: No, I was hoping that would act as the href attribute of the element with ID: rss-link but it didnt, i meant to remove that from the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery plugin you are using automatically creates elements or you. So you do not need to manually set the link on the a tags. You probably want to specify the template with the correct tokens in the options while calling the plugin.

```
<body>
    <div id="rss-feed"></div>
    <script>
        var rssUrl="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss";
        $('#rss-feed').rss(rssUrl, {
           entryTemplate: '<a href="{url}">{title}</a>'
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

You can see a more elaborate template on the library's [Demo Page](http://embed.plnkr.co/WQRoCYLld162uplnz1rc/preview). You can refer to the [Readme.md of the library](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) and look under Templating for more information on the template structure and available tokens.